# Is it possible to truncate an array of derived classes into an array of base classes in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, opengl, casting

I'm making an application which uses OpenGL and currently store an array of objects that should be rendered each frame which look something like this:

```
class Object {
  private:
    float x;
    float y;
  public:
    void func1();
    void func2();
    ...
};
```

I'd like to be able to create a vertex buffer object from the array of these objects, but I can't simply pass the array since the class contains the additional functions which `glBufferData` doesn't expect.

Would it be possible to separate the object class like so:

```
class baseObject {
  public:
    float x;
    float y;
};

class derivedObject : public baseObject {
  public:
    float x;
    float y;
    void func1();
    void func2();
    ...
};
```

and then cast an array of `derivedObjects` into an array of `baseObjects` using `static_cast` or otherwise which can then be passed to `glBufferData`? Or is the only way to iterate through the array of Objects, extracting the `x` and `y` variables into a separate array which can then be passed to `glBufferData`?

Comment: Are you saying that both the base and derived class have a separate float x & y?

Comment: Why can't you just pass in the array?  The functions aren't stored with the data members.

Comment: The `float x...y` in `derivedObject` are redundant.  Being derived from `baseObject`, `derivedObject` will contain the data members from the parent class.

Comment: @gamernb @Grant: Yeah i messed that bit up, there should only be only copy of x and y. @genpfault: Thanks, I just assumed they were stored as part of the objec tin memory but you're right, it does work without modification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions in your class `Object` don't actually contribute anything to the object's layout.  Although the spec doesn't guarantee this, on all major compilers the in-memory representation of an object is just its fields.  (If you add a virtual function into the mix, though, this isn't true).  In your case, your `Object` class would look indistinguishable from this `struct` in memory:

```
struct JustObjectFields {
    float x, y;
};
```

Because when you remove the member functions, this is what you're left with.

The reason for this is that member functions are typically compiled down to regular functions that take the `this` pointer as an explicit first argument.  This code is separate from any one instance of the class, and so the class size isn't affected by them.  In short, you should be able to do this without using inheritance at all.  Just use your raw `Object` class.

Comment: Thanks, I had just assumed it would not work due to the functions being stored as part of the object in memory, but it seems I was wrong, and have an easier time ahead of me because of it :)

Comment: +1. If I remember correctly, according to C++0x Object is a POD type, so such behavior will become guaranteed in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array of base class pointers and manually point them to the elements in the derived class array. However, you cannot do any kind of fancy cast on the array itself because array offsets depend on knowing the actual size of each element. With pointers, this is not a problem, but with actual instances in an array, you'd run into lots of crashing when you try to access individual elements using a pointer of the wrong type.

Answer (score 0):

Typecast for arrays doesn't work in such case - http://codepad.org/6DFLPPDH
In general, its impossible to transform an array of derived objects into
array of base objects without moving the data, and I guess nobody bothered
to support specifically the case where derived class only adds methods.
In fact, even array pointer cast is not very reliable - http://codepad.org/15a4cCy9
But with plain pointers its certainly not a problem - http://codepad.org/4vEK5wY1
And in your case it should be ok anyway, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes.  If `glBufferData` accepts `baseObject` as a parameter, then `derivedObject` may also be used, since an instance of class `derivedObject` is also an instance of class `baseObject`.

The issue here isn't methods/functions, but data.  `glBufferData` expects an instance of class `baseObject` as a parameter because the method requires an object containing exactly the data members described in `baseObject`.  `Object` is invalid as a parameter because its data members may differ from `baseObject`.  This could prove disastrous if the method is passed an object with invalid data.

However, by defining `derivedObject` as inheriting from `baseObject`, we are saying that `derivedObject` **IS** a `baseObject` *plus* all the data members listed in `derivedObject`'s definition.  So, when we pass an instance of `derivedObject` to `glBufferData`, it can treat it like an instance of `baseObject` without danger.